# Regular Expression of a particular String in PHP

Tags: php, regex, regular-language

I have this  few strings:

```
'user/1/myid_print'
'user/2/myid_print'
'user/3/myid_print'
'user/4/myid_print'
'user/5/myid_print'
```

The second part is the dynamic one which must contain only integers. What is it's regular expression?

Comment: Try this one: `^'user/\d*/myid_print'$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
/user\/\d+\/myid_print/
```

the `\d+` matches a number which contains at least one digit.
if it is a non-zero number, replace the `\d+` with `[1-9]\d*`

Comment: It works, but why does we have to put / in the beginning and end of the expression?

Comment: @Aliyah, It is the default regex delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on what language you're using, but one valid answer for Python is:

```
user/\d/myid_print
```

The `/` character is often used in describing regular expressions and sometimes needs `\` before it to make it match part of the string, a valid answer might be:

```
user\/\d\/myid_print
```

These match the text "user/" and "/myid_print" literally, and `\d` matches the pattern "any digit 0-9". If you need to match the numbers 1,2,3,4,5 only, then use `[1-5]` instead of `\d`

Test it here: https://regex101.com/r/mS4xN4/1